# Get Real Shipment ID

Tags: module, magento-1, shipping, shipment

I am able to retrieve the real order id by

```
$order->getReadlOrderId();
```

I am unable to find any documentation or posts that show how to get the real shipment id, so far I am only able to get the Id by

```
$shipment->getId();
```

And that Id is not the Id shown on the adminhtml grids... any ideas on how I can get the real shipment id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$shipment->getIncrementId();
```

In fact, you can use `getIncrementId` on credit memos and invoices, too.

---

After all, `getRealOrderId` is just an alias for `increment_id`:

**Mage_Sales_Model_Order**

```
public function getRealOrderId()
{
    $id = $this->getData('real_order_id');
    if (is_null($id)) {
        $id = $this->getIncrementId();
    }
    return $id;
}
```

I'm not sure of the history, but `real_order_id` looks to be a remnant deprecated by standardization of `increment_id` - it was once a column value in some modules including the flat order grid.